# Increase space of /var folder in centos

Tags: linux, centos

I want to increase the space of /var folder.The output of df -h is

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_root   50G   33G   16G  68% /
tmpfs                          5.8G  296K  5.8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                      485M  127M  334M  28% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_home  862G  9.3G  809G   2% /home


[root@localhost ~]# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg_livecd lvm2 a--  931.02g    0 
[root@localhost ~]# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg_livecd   1   3   0 wz--n- 931.02g    0 
[root@localhost ~]# lvs
  LV      VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_home vg_livecd -wi-ao---- 875.20g                                             
  lv_root vg_livecd -wi-ao----  50.00g                                             
  lv_swap vg_livecd -wi-ao----   5.82g
```

I tried searching it but unable to solve my problem.
Can anybody point me to the right direction.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your df output, your /var folder is located on the same partition as the root folder /. You also seem to be running from a livecd image ... all changes will most likely be undone after reboot :-/

In any case, if you're using LVM, you can add disk space (as in a whole disk, or separate partition), and add it to the volume where your /var folder is located.

fdisk /dev/sdb

- create as many partitions as you need using command n
- Label them with command t as 8e for making it Linux LVM
- Write and Exit with the command w.

Format your partitions

- mkfs -t ext4 -c /dev/sdb1

LVM commands

- pvcreate /dev/sdb1; to create the physical volume
- vgdisplay ; to display your current volume groups
- vgextend  /dev/sdb1; to add the disk to the volume group
- lvextend -L 15G {your logical volume} ;for extending your volume to 15GB
- lvextend -L+1G {your logical volume} ;for adding one more GB to your volume
- ext2online {your logical volume} ;for resizing the Logical Volumes

If you want to separate /var from your root volume, just create a new volume, copy all the /var contents to it, rename or remove your existing /var folder, create a new /var directory and mount the new volume on it.